# Excel Big Data Calculation (PCA...)

Tags: python, r, excel, pca

I have to do some calculation on data stored in excel for my internship.
I am supposed to aggregate market datas (50 assets over 15 years) and do a Principal Component Analysis over the aggregated datas.

For the moment I have the market data in a worksheet, I save it as a tabulation separated text (like csv but with tabulation instead of commas). Then I read it with R and use some powerfull package to do the PCA. Finally, with R I create another tabulation separated text and read it trough excel. I now have datas and results in excel and I can plot everything I want.

The problem is that the process is not enough automated for my colleagues.
As they said, they want a button in excel which launch the PCA when clicked.

I've tried to install some Excel Package (Rexcel) which allow to use R function directly in excel. It's not working (a server problem) and not well documented. So I'm trying to find others way to do big calculation directly in excel. It seems that there is the same kind of package to use Python in Excel. I've also heard about other powerfull langage compatible with excel. The problem is that I can't install what I want on my computer (yeah I have to call an IT guy for every package I want to install...), so it already took me 2/3 days to try the R solution. This is also why i'm looking for a simple solution, my colleagues won't have 2/3 days to install some excel package to use my macro...

So i'm here to ask: what would be the easiest way to do PCA, using tools from other languages, directly in excel ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You could try to write a [Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) app that reads in an Excel file and writes to a new worksheet. But without packages you won't have much success. I've played a bit with RExcel and was able to integrate R in a VBA script, but Excel did not react well if the R code needed some time to finish. Generally, I am not in favor of providing people with statistical tools if they insist on using Excel for the analysis.

Comment: The only things working are the programs from MS Office... I'm glad they didn't ask me to use Powerpoint for the analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the very handy executable `Rscript`to launch automatically your R scripts.

Within VBA you create a macro where you type something like this :

```
  retVal = Shell(MY_RSCRIPT_BAT, vbNormalFocus)  ## vba code here
```

I assume that you can call a VBA macro from a button.

your MY_RSCRIPT_BAT , is .bat file where you type something like:

```
@echo off
C:
PATH R_PATH;%path%
cd DEMO_PATH
Rscript your_pca_script.R 
exit
```